# javascript class, method that returns a possible error to handle it

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class, I would like an error method to return a way to handle it from the object

```
class MyClass {
On(value){
     try{
     throw new Error("Massimo due candidati");
      }
      catch(e){
              console.log(e.name, e.message); //Error, I'm Evil
      }
}
}
```

If I create an object of the class how can I handle the error in a similar way?

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.on(value, err=> {
if (err) {
    onError(err.message);
  }else{
    console.log("Inserimento ok");
  }
});
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `.on` is called, push the callback to an array of callbacks stored by the object. Then, whenever whatever triggers the `.on` runs, iterate through all callbacks in the array and invoke them (and possibly pass an error argument too):

```js
class MyClass {
  onCallbacks = [];
  on(someArg, callback) {
    this.onCallbacks.push(callback);
  }
  invokeOK() {
    this.onCallbacks.forEach((callback) => {
      callback();
    });
  }
  invokeError() {
    this.onCallbacks.forEach((callback) => {
      callback(new Error('foo'));
    });
  }
}

const onError = console.error;
const obj = new MyClass();
obj.on('value', err => {
  if (err) {
    onError(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Inserimento ok");
  }
});

obj.invokeError();
obj.invokeOK();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.
I think in my head I wanted to do this ...

```
class MyClass {
  onCallbacks = [];
  on(someArg, callback) {
    if (someArg != 'value') {
        this.onCallbacks.push(callback);
    }else{
    console.log("start ok");
    }
  }
  invokeOK() {
  //if (this.onCallbacks.length==0){return;}
    this.onCallbacks.forEach((callback) => {
      callback();
    });
  }
  invokeError() {
    this.onCallbacks.forEach((callback) => {
      callback(new Error('foo'));
    });
  }
}

const onError = console.error;
const obj = new MyClass();

obj.on('value', err => {
  if (err) {
    onError(err.message);
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});
obj.invokeError();
obj.invokeOK();
```

If it seems wrong to you as a process, let me know.